# DB connectivity using angular, php, mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

Hi I am having some trouble with a small project. It's my first time using mySQL and PHP so I'm just trying to get connectivity for now. I have followed some tutorials and I cannot connect to the database, I am getting the "Sorry! Data Couldnt be inserted!" error from my php script at the bottom of index.html.

I also have a password on the database for the root user however even when i type this in the php file it still wont work.

Any help is much appreciated guys.

index.html:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class= "container" style = "width:500px">
      <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type ="text" name="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control"/>
             <br />
             <label>Password</label>
            <input type ="text" name="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control"/>
            <br /> 
            <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" ng-click="insertData()" value="ADD"/>
      </div>
      </div>



 <script>
   var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

   app.controller('usercontroller', function($scope, $http){
      $scope.insertData = function(){
        $http.post(
          "insert.php",{
            'email':$scope.email,
            'password':$scope.password
          }).then(function(response){
            alert("Data inserted Successfully! YIPEEEE!!!");
            console.log("Data inserted Successfully");
        },function(error){
          alert("Sorry! Data Couldnt be inserted!");
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
   });
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

and my insert.php:

```html
<?php
//insert.php


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


    $email =  $data->email;
    $password = $data->password;

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");

    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO 'test_user'('email', 'password') VALUES ('".$email."','".$password."')") or die(mysql_error());

    echo $email. " " .$password;

/*
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
        echo "User inserted...";
    }
    else{
        echo "User not inserted...";
    }
*/

#mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,
#mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, 
?>
```

Comment: Why are you decoding JSON in the PHP file?

Comment: I have no idea I was literally following a tutorial.

Comment: you are parsing a JSON when I don't think you have

Comment: I removed it and it doesn't make a difference. :-(  I'm really stuck here

Answer (score 0):

> It's my first time using mySQL and PHP

But you seem to be using a very old version of PHP (the mysql_ extension is deprecated).

I'm not familiar with Angular but it looks like your code relies on Angular to determine if the PHP script ran as intended. Angular can't base that decision on the content sent by your script, therefore it must be basing its decision on the HTTP status returned by your script (which has no debugging in it). I expecting your PHP code is crashing and burning before it gets to run the insert.

I suggest you:

1) build a test rig using a textare and NO javascript to fire a request at your insert.php script

2) amend your PHP script so that it
  - captures more information about the processing
  - uses appropriate [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and ensure your error logging is working
  - presents the (appropriate) details of the actions it took in a parseable format (i.e. JSON)

3) read your log files - for both PHP and MySQL (you might want to do this before going to the trouble of changing/verifying your logging as described above)

4) read up on [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: So I know a little about SQL injection. This is only a college project so i'm not overly worried about that for now.  I have tried with just html and no javascript and it still doesnt work for me. I an coding in ubuntu using visual code and using the ng commands for angular to generate components and run a server etc as this is the only way I have used angular before. I am still in college learning this stuff so bare with me please ;-) anybody have a link to someone who has done this before? preferably in ubuntu using LAMP

Comment: "doesn't work for me" is not a useful diagnostic message.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me tell where the app is failing! If i knew that do you not think I would google the error? or post it on here asking for help? No error message apart from the on given in the index.html ie "alert("Sorry! Data Couldnt be inserted!");" if i remove this line of code and run there are no errors, no insertions into the database nothing! So how do i give you a useful diagnostic message when I dont get any messages?

Comment: All I want is to be able to connect with this database. I have only used angular in a specific environment before(on an ubuntu virtual machine not running LAMP) this required me to have no connection with a database. Now I need it connect it to a MySQL database using PHP both of which I have never used before and I cant even find a simple way of testing the connection to the database or anything? As far as I can see (as you stated) the app is not reaching the insert and I doubt its even running the PHP code at all.

Comment: You have three calls to mysql_ functions in the code above and never check the return value not poll mysql_error(). I suggested that you also validate your error reporting - that means creating a php script which you know will throw an error and make sure that its is being captured where you expect to find it. "I doubt its even running the PHP code at all" - the answer to this is already in your webserver logs.